# :target not working to change text-color

Tags: jquery, html, css

stackoverflow, long time no see

So, I am in the process of converting my website to pure CSS3 - just for the fun of it, or basically to not use jQuery. And I ran into a small problem when trying to update my current menu.

The page is a "one page" in a way, so there is only 1 index.html. The problem is, that I am currently using jQuery to change the text-color of the current section/page as follow:

**Menu:**

```
<div id="menuDiv">
                <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about" class="2 scroll" onclick="setMenuStyle(this); return false;">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#background" class="3 scroll" onclick="setMenuStyle(this);">background</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#mindset" class="4 scroll" onclick="setMenuStyle(this);">mindset</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#vision" class="5 scroll" onclick="setMenuStyle(this);">vision</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 0.93em">
                        <a href="#home" class="1 scroll" title="HOME"><img src="gfx/home.png" alt="HOME" /></a>

                        <a href="https://dk.linkedin.com/in/rbfmnpwr" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn"><img src="gfx/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>

                        <a href="#contact" class="6 scroll" title="Contact"><img src="gfx/contact.png" alt="Contact" /></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#thanks" class="7 scroll"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    getHash();
});

// Keep track of our current state
currentSection = 1;

function getHash() {

    jQuery('.scroll').on('click', function () {
        // Get our new state
        var nr = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
        // Calculate the difference, with element height of 560px using formular dest = (newPows - currentPos) * elmHeight
        var scrollTop = (nr - currentSection) * 560;
        jQuery('#contentDiv').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTop
        }, 400);
        return false;

    });
}

function setMenuStyle(ele) {
    // Reset menu
    jQuery("#menu li a").each(function () {
        var child = jQuery(this);
        child.attr('style', '');
    });

    // Set menu style
    ele = jQuery(ele);
    ele.attr('style', 'color:#009688;');
}
```

However, I would like to du this color change purely by CSS. So I though, "hey, why not use :target to do so. But it just wont work, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect the position of the scrollbar using pure CSS. Moreover, `:target` is used to style an element when its `id` is refered to by an anchor, or as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) puts it:

> The :target pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document.

For example if the URI is `http://example.com/index.html#heading1`, the element with a `id="heading1"` can be styled using `:target` pseudo selector.

Here's a [working example](http://webdesignernotebook.com/examples/target.html).

**Other cool stuff you can do with `:target`:**

- [Pure `CSS` Modals](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)
- [Pure CSS Side Menu](https://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/)
- [Pure CSS Slidshow](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-slideshow-without-page-jump)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply. However, I am also in the process of changing the "scroll" mechanism to CSS as well, which hopefully will work. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/ - would I be able to use :target, or something similar to achieve the effect in pure CSS?